# How to I automate creating a script with an input parameter?

Tags: python, automation, scripting

I have a folder of similar-looking scripts which scrape google alerts from their RSS feeds.

All the files are exactly the same except the variable `uniqueurl` at the end of url

```
url = 'https://www.google.co.in/alerts/feeds/*uniqueurl*'
resp = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(resp.text, 'html.parser')

output = []
for entry in soup.find_all('entry'):

    item = {
        'Title': entry.find('title', {'type': 'html'}).text,
        'Pubdate': entry.find('published').text,
        'Content': entry.find('content').text,
        'Link': entry.find('link')['href']
    }

    output.append(item)

df = pd.DataFrame(output)
df.to_csv('google_alert.csv',index=False)
```

How do I run a command like `python create.py uniqueurl` which generates the above file with just the url variable updated with what is passed in the command?

Comment: Do you really need a separate script for each URL? Why not just use an argument provided at runtime?

Comment: Because the results returned are added over existing CSVs and there are various categories that I've separated them for NLP later.

Comment: That still does not mean you cannot use a runtime argument and decide a category based on that during runtime.

Comment: How can I add a list of URLs and set their destinations too?

Answer (score 0):

Use sys.argv to capture any variables you want to get at runtime each time the script is executed.

```
import sys

uniqueUrl = sys.argv[1]

url = f'https://www.google.co.in/alerts/feeds/{uniqueUrl}'
print(uniqueUrl)
destination = sys.argv[2]
print(destination)

resp = requests.get(url)
```

Then when running a script you can pass a value that will be assigned to those variables like so:
`python script.py uniqueUrl Category` - that way you don't need to store multiple scripts and regenerate them every time you want to make some small difference in the code.